# Physical validity of taking limits inside an integrand

Tags: integration, approximations, signal-processing

Consider an integral expression  for the spectrum, $$I(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(\omega,t)dt\tag{1}$$
with
$$G(\omega,t)=g(\omega,t)e^{t/\tau}.$$
Here $t$ is time, $\omega$  is frequency and $\tau$ is correlation time (a constant). Now suppose I am interested in the case where $t<<\tau$, then one could write $$G(\omega,t)=g(\omega,t)e^{t/\tau}\approx g(\omega,t)(1+\frac{t}{\tau})\tag{2}$$

and use the last expression as the integrand.
However, is this simple procedure trouble free? I have seen procedures like this being performed regularly, but it seems to me that this process is not correct. Because, the integration variable x ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and close to the upper limit the case $t<<\tau$ doesn't apply if we assume that $\tau$ is a finite value. Is my reasoning correct? If so, are there mathematically correct ways to study the $t<<\tau$ case? The common reply I hear from colleagues is that the above discussed procedure is acceptable physically, even though it's wrong mathematically. Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

In general you are correct.

But it might be a valid approximation depending on the function $g(\omega,t)$. If $g(\omega,t)$ has almost no contribution to the integral for $t>\tau$ and it goes faster to zero than $\exp(t/\tau)$ grows to infinity for $t\rightarrow \infty$, than you could argue along the lines

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(\omega,t)\exp(t/\tau) dt \approx \int_{t_0}^{t_1} g(\omega,t)(1+t/\tau)dt \approx \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(\omega,t)(1+t/\tau)$, where $|t_{0,1}| \ll \tau$ and

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(\omega,t) dt \approx \int_{t_0}^{t_1} g(\omega,t) dt$.

The question is how crude the approximation can be?